# XnaSerializer в Monogame

Tags: xna, monogame

Изучая руководство отсюда: [XNA Game Programming Adventures
XNA 4.0 RPG Tutorials](http://xnagpa.net/xna4rpg.php)

В одном из уроков наткнулся на `XnaSerializer` из

`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Intermediate`

Однако ни в `XNA`, ни в `Monogame` не могу найти это пространство имен.

Подскажите где найти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищите в `SDK` сборку `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline` и подключайте её к проекту в `Solution Explorer'е`. Но помните:

- Эта сборка не включена в `XNA Redistributable`, поэтому не стоит использовать её в рантайме (только в `build time` для подготовки контента);
- Эта сборка работает только под Windows, под `Xbox` и `Windows Phone` её нет.

Источники: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.serialization.intermediate.aspx), [2](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/57424.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, а под Monogame ее не существует? Т.е. я не смогу ее использовать в проекте monogame?

Конечно пока что она включена только в редактор, но я честно говоря не знаю что там дальше в серии уроков.

Comment: Разработчики Monogame не стали писать свою реализацию Content Pipeline и просто реюзнули реализацию Майкрософта. При создании проекта Monogame должны появиться два проекта: собственно игра (полностью под Monogame) и проект для компиляции ресурсов (там используется майкрософтовский Pipeline). Нужно компилировать ресурсы во втором проекте, и они должны появиться в первом. [Источник][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625189/monogame-content-pipeline-dont-work

Comment: Альтернативный подход - компилировать ресурсы отдельно с помощью [XNA Content Compiler][1] и вручную перекидывать их в папку Content вашего проекта.

  [1]: http://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/